# my application is not searchable on android market

Tags: android, google-play

I have just published my application on the android market. After doing that I went on the android market and searched my application by name, no results came up. What could be the reason?

How long does it take for a published android application to be visible on the android market?

Edit:

My app did show up, it took about an hour. I guess the time for your app to be available once you publish it depends on the traffic on android market at that time.

Answer (score 4):

It can take up to more than 10 hours for your application to show up.

Have you tried a direct link? I.e. `market://search?q=pname:your.package.name.here`?

Comment: Please, provide a link to 10 hours. I haven't got this situation.

Comment: No reference link available. This is just from my observations.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=2168efe87f5f8491&hl=en) you've got possible answers.